# tell if a given element is in a list of doubles

Tags: list, prolog, tuples

I've got a list of doubles in the form `A = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[5,5]]`

What I'm trying to do is create a function that will return true if a number is the first number in any of the doubles. So `somefunction(7,A)` would return false and `somefunction(5,A)` would return true.

I've tried this `somefunction(A,B) :- A == (B,_)` but this doesn't do anything of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it recursively like this:

Check to see if the value is at the head of the list:

```
somefunction(A,[[A,_]|_]).
```

Then recursively check to see if the value is in the rest of the list:

```
somefunction(A,[BH|BT]) :- somefunction(A,BT).
```

Comment: in order to just keep the unique elements so if `A = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[2,2],[4,4]]` would output `B = [[2,2],[4,4]]`

Comment: @Vaughn Cato:  Consider to `member/2` **directly**. That is `member([A,_],Xs)`. This is often more efficient: First, it is more compact and readable (efficient to the programmer who has to read code), and second more efficient in its execution since `member/2` is often more determinate than a direct definition.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to doing the recursion yourself, you could use the "higher order" predicate `maplist/3` combined with `nth0/3` to select only the first elements of the lists and then issue a `member/2` call on the result to achieve what you want:

```
somefunction(Element, List) :-
    maplist(nth0(0), List, Firsts),
    member(Element, Firsts).
```

Comment: -1: This solution is more verbose than the direct solution, requires iterating the source list to construct a second list and then requires iterating over the second list. Contrast that to the direct solution which simply does a tail-recursive iteration over the source list.

Comment: I found these downvotes to be confusing. false and Mog, chac etc. add such value by explaining different ways to achieve the same end, and don't claim the best solution - just an alternate solution.  Surely adding a comment to the efficiency is sufficient for others to upvote other solutions. In my mind, their reputation increases by providing alternate solutions.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: you miss the point of my answer. There are far worse answers to downvote around here, but well...

Comment: and it's not more verbose. My variables have meaningful names, that's the only difference :) I'll add too that going through a list twice still is the same complexity, and that if you feel better thinking with usual idioms of functional programming then by no means you should prevent yourself from using them.

Comment: @Mog: Nit: It's high**er** order, and +1 to avoid any ambiguity

Answer (score 2):

`member([N,_],As).`

But there are two remarks here:

First, do you really want lists like `[[1,2],[3,4]]`? If you will always have exactly two elements, consider to use pairs. That is, use the functor `(-)/2`. It is often written `Key-Value`. You would thus write `[1-2,3-4]`. Lists of pairs are commonly used, there is `keysort/2` which sorts only according to the `Key`.

Second, a frequent idiom for "name lookup" is the following:

```
..., P = (Name-Value), member(P, Dict), ...
```

What is remarkable here is that we do not need a "special" member predicate for lists of pairs or whatever other elements we have. We might search now "by name" or "by value" or both or none ...